# How to iterate a table in JSP using Struts tags?

Tags: java, struts2

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="boxtbl">
  <th rowspan="2" class="fntnrml" colspan="5">Trip ID</th>
  <bean:write name="loan" property="tripID1" /> 
  <td><html:checkbox property="ZAXY" /></td>
  <td><bean:write name="loan" property="Profile11" /></td>
  <td><bean:write name="loan" property="StartDt11" /></td>
</table>
```

How to iterate the above table? I read that only collections can be iterated. But I am also using "checkbox" inside the `<td>`. How to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display single table has multiple tables by iteration

You can use any JSTL or Struts tag iterator to iterate a table

For Example

```
<s:iterator value="listObject">
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="boxtbl">
  <th rowspan="2" class="fntnrml" colspan="5">Trip ID</th>
  <bean:write name="loan" property="tripID1" /> 
  <td><html:checkbox property="ZAXY" /></td>
  <td><bean:write name="loan" property="Profile11" /></td>
  <td><bean:write name="loan" property="StartDt11" /></td>
</table>
</s:iterate>
```

Comment: thanks for the response.. but i am using struts1. what is the syntax for that.

Comment: YOu can use the same as above just add <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %> taglib to your jsp OR You can use JSTL core TAG <c:forEach var="listObject" items="$listObject"></c:foreach>